# Hybrid Federated Search Results in SharePoint 2013 From SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, search-results

I am trying to setup a federated search between our SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2010 Farms. I want to show search results from SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 in my new SharePoint 2013 environment.

Is it possible to show federated search results from older version into later version of SharePoint?

I have seen multiple articles on setting up federated search including Microsoft but they all shows the same SharePoint version i.e online and on-premises.

Method i have tried so far.

**1.** Building Server to Server trust and publishing SharePoint 2010 Search Service to SharePoint 2013. (Both Web Applications on Classic Mode Authentication however i am unable to use the published service. I get multiple errors while using the published service related to Schema Property error and services Contract Mismatch.)

**2.** Configuring Remote SharePoint result sources and Query Rules

**3.** Creating new content source and providing SharePoint 2010 URL in it for crawling. (This method crawled only root site collection)

Any other possible way to achieve the target? Am i looking on the wrong side to do the stuff? Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand, you trying to consume the SharePoint 2010 search in SharePoint 2013 which will not work.

What you have to do.

- Create a search service application in 2013 farm, this is your publishing farm
- Build the trust between other 2 farms( 2010 & 2013) farms. both farms will be consuming.
- after completing all steps to establishing trust then you have to make sure that default content access account has read permission on all web apps which you want crawl.

Here is good article to establish trust between farm.https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2013/09/03/cross-farm-service-applications-integration-between-two-separate-sharepoint-farms/

Comment: Thank you Waqas. I was expecting your reply on this and you understood it correct. I have already done what you have suggested. Thanks again. I am able to consume SharePoint 2013 Search Service in SharePoint 2010 and it shows me results as expected. I am still unable to find on Technet or MSDN where Microsoft claims that we cannot consume SharePoint 2010 services (i.e Search, Metadata) in SharePoint 2013. That would be really helpful to convince if i get a word from Microsoft on it. :)

Comment: I can see this for SharePoint 2016 that it cannot consume services from SharePoint 2013. See here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621100(v=office.16).aspx . Thanks

Comment: I dont know why MSFT not mention it...here is from msdn blogs( official)..This only works one way and a SharePoint 2013 farm can not consume services from a SharePoint 2010 provider https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alimaz/2012/08/07/service-application-federation-between-sharepoint-2013-public-preview-and-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: thank you for expecting a reply from me, is it really helpful or i am too talkative?

Comment: You are helpful to me multiple times as i mostly follow your answers and most of the time i got success. Thanks for being there. Yes i saw that blog by Ali Mazaheri and read his thought on "One Way". Although its from a MVP but still a word direct from Microsoft, values more to its clients than any of its employee. I wish i could be able to connect Microsoft MSDN and Technet authors if they can correct this in their blog.

Comment: for that you have to contact the MSFT but honestly i think this is enough information to prove it / believe it.

Comment: I created the trust relationship and i was able to publish SharePoint 2013 Search Service to SharePoint 2010. We can select only one Search Service instance in Service Application Association in SharePoint environment so i changed it to the 2013 one. However, requirements changed and we crawled whole SharePoint 2010 environment from SharePoint 2013 and switched the SharePoint 2010 Search Centers to show result in SharePoint 2013. This worked fine for me so marking it as answer. Thank you Waqas.

Comment: Made my day, I am happy I was able to help u. If you like me go n visit election page and vote for me. Thanks

Comment: Guess what? I already did that couple of days ago.